# Algorithm for finding generators of an ideal

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be a field, and $f:k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]\to k[y_1,\ldots,y_m]$ a $k$-algebra homomorphism. Given $r_1,\ldots,r_k\in k[y_1,\ldots,y_m]$, is there an algorithm for producing a finite generating set for the ideal $f^{-1}((r_1,\ldots,r_k))$?

Comment: I wonder if there is even a reasonable algorithm for finding generators of $f^{-1}(0)$.

Comment: Will Grobner bases help?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes. The question is asking to compute the kernel of

$$f : k[x_1, \dots, x_n] \rightarrow S$$

where $S$ is some quotient of a polynomial ring. [Macaulay2](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/Macaulay2/doc/Macaulay2-1.5/share/doc/Macaulay2/Macaulay2Doc/html/_kernel_lp__Ring__Map_rp.html) can calculate such a kernel.